# Can't get Apps exchanging information via HTTP get/post

Tags: google-apps-script

My scenario:
I've got an AppsScript application running as user1 published as a Web App. In it I've implemented doGet().
I've got another Appscript application running as user2. I try to do a URLFetch on the published URL and get back a bunch of HTML indicating that the requestor needs to logon.
If I do the same URL fetch from the browser as 'user2', the doGet() is accessed perfectly and returns what I need.

It seems you can't make get (or post - I tried both) HTTP requests between Appscript applications. N.B. Both users are on the same domain and as stated above, it works when user initiated from the browser. It's like the user's identity isn't being passed from App to App.

This is a test case as I'm trying to work out the best way of moving data from one application to another. Google has the ContentService for returning data but I want to push data. Push is best for the architecture I'm considering as there will be several apps (10+) trying to push to the one app at any one time, so scaling is important. The ContentService lends itself to a polling approach which won't scale if the one app, polls the other 10. Will get timeouts etc.  Any tips re: such an architecture appreciated.  The other option I've got is for the 10 apps to write directly to the ScriptDB attached to the main app. I don't like this option because the only way to share a ScriptDB is at the project level and every app will be able to see everything in the ScriptDB and there will be no isolation of data at the app level. I realise I'm pushing the boundaries of what's possible with Appscript and fully expect that as an answer, but with the new offerings in AppScript, Enterprise level customers are considering these approaches for lightweight apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that you can't have one script call another (you absolutely can) but that UrlFetchApp, by design, doesn't pass along the authentication of the user at the keyboard. (The reasons for this are outside the scope of this answer; suffice it to say that they are security-related, common to many app-hosting platforms, and not likely to change anytime soon.) So the only way you can call another script is if the script being called is published as available to anonymous users (which implies that it must be running as the script owner, as Henrique said).

However, what you want to do is trivially supported by the libraries feature. If script A wants to notify script B of something, and have script B take an action while preserving the user authentication of script A, all you need to do is include B as a library dependency of A and add a function to B that A can call when it wants to push a notification.

Comment: Yeah, anonymous publishing is not going to work for this. However, the Library feature works great. Who'd have thought, RPC for free with Library calls across apps. Raises questions on visibility of code and its container though. You have to share a Library (Project) with at least read permission to the user who is going to use the Library. This lets them access your code and the container. If you're a vendor, this is not a great idea. You want to keep your IP secure. It works fine for small apps, but wonder what limitations there will be for multiple apps using a common library?

Comment: You can hide code with an intermediate library right now, which just delegates to a "real" library that you don't give out access to, although this is an interesting point that we can look into.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this in-between Apps Script doGet calls with this new 'run as the user' option. But when running as the developer it used to work fine for me.

Also, importing the main app and push the data to it directly does not have to necessarily expose anything. It all depends on the "interface" you build (public methods that do not finish with an underscore). You don't need to pass the db instance object. The main script can receive the objected to be saved and do it itself.

Hope this helps.